# Can I load flex components asynchronously?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a flex application that shows information gathered from different external services by using rest api. Some of them are resource intensive, take longer to response. Is there any way I can load the different components asyncronously?

Answer (score 2):

ActionScript (Flex) executes asynchronously by default. So, if you make concurrent calls to a service, ensure that your code handles the results appropriately (via Event handlers). By default, making a request to a web service operation that is already executing does not cancel the existing request.

So, simply invoke your services, and register (result/failure) event handlers on them to capture their responses, and load the components accordingly.